# Scraping Google search results was working yesterday, now it doesn't

Tags: python, for-loop, beautifulsoup, request

So my program yesterday was working, i save it and close it and now its not. the first for loop is supposed to append website links from a google search and now its not running the loop at all

```
import bs4
import requests


def Google(word):

    linkelem = []
    strlink = []
    httplink = []
    extractedhttp = []
    brokenlinks = []

    websiteheadlines = []
    websitebody = []

    res2 = requests.get(f'https://google.com/search?q={word}')
    res2.raise_for_status()

    soup2 = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res2.text, 'html.parser')
    #print(soup2)

    for div in soup2.find_all("div", {"class": "jfp3ef"}):
        for link in div.select("a"):
            linkelem.append(link)
```

i need it to append the link into the list "linkelem"

this is the section that isn't working, there is more to it but it all relies on this first part to work. if i need to add the rest though i can. i tried adding print statements in the for loop and it didn't print them. i didn't know what to do after that.

Comment: Pretty sure `jfp3ef` is a random class that is changed every now and then to prevent bots such as yours. Looking into the source code of this page you're requesting I don't find this anywhere.

Comment: Also you're not supposed to be scrapping their website like this anyway, they offer proper API for that https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview

Comment: ah shoot i didn't know that, that's super helpful thank you very much! @Havenard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most obvious one that [Havenard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57446163/scraping-google-search-results-was-working-yesterday-now-it-doesnt#comment101368543_57446163) suggested is that the class has been changed. Also, it might be because your requests don't have a `user-agent` to fake a real user visit. [List of user agents](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/guides/the-latest-user-agent/).

```py
headers = {
  "User-Agent":
  "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

requests.get('YOUR_URL', headers=headers)
```

You can always check if this class exists or not by checking it via `if` statement:

```py
# scrapes all titles from page result
# try to remove one letter from CSS selector and it will print "Nothing has been found."
if soup.select('.DKV0Md'):
  print('Found elements:')
  for result in soup.select('.DKV0Md'):
    print(result.text)
else:
  print('Nothing has been found.')

# output:
'''
Found elements:
Minecraft Official Site | Minecraft
Minecraft - Wikipedia
Minecraft - Apps on Google Play
Minecraft - YouTube
'''
```

Code:

```py
import requests, lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent":
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

params = {'q': 'Minecraft'}

html = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search', headers=headers, params=params).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

if soup.select('.DKV0Md'):
  print('Found elements:')
  for result in soup.select('.DKV0Md'):
    print(result.text)
else:
  print('Nothing has been.')
```

---

Alternatively, you can do it as well by using [Google Search Engine Results API](https://serpapi.com/search-api) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free trial of 5,000 searches.

Code to integrate:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
import os

params = {
  "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
  "engine": "google",
  "q": "Minecraft",
  "hl": "en",
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

for result in results['organic_results']:
# try/except is better is this case.
# If nothing has been found, it will just print 'Nothing has been found.'
  try:  
    print('Found elements:')
    title = result['title']
    print(title)
  except:
    print('Nothing has been found.')
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.